# Empty Entity kind dropdown menu in google App Engine Datastore view

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am learning to develop a mobileAssistant app using google app engine and am following google cloud tutorial. But i Am badly stuck at a situation. When I try to debug my MobileAssistant. I get nothing when i open http://localhost:8888 in my browser to check whether my client and backend is communicating or not.
Entity kind drop down menu is also blank.

Pls help me with this?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. It might help to review [ask].

Comment: Have you actually **created** any entities in your local datastore?  If not, then of course the Entity Kind drop-down menu's going to be empty, because there **are** no entities in your datastore yet.  The localhost URL you mention will visit whatever code you've written to serve your app's `/` (root) -- if nothing shows, look at the logs, you may see error messages there.

Comment: Yes I Have created an entity named CheckIn Entity using this code: CheckIn checkin = new CheckIn();
checkin.setPlaceId("StoreNo123");

Comment: I' m Also Getting this message in console:............INFO: The backing store, C:\MY DATA\study material new\Eclipse Juno Projects\Android1\MobileAssistant-AppEngine\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin, does not exist. It will be created....I dont know what does it mean...does this mean that my local datastore is not created?

Comment: After Block by block testing i came across a possible cause for my error : This Block Is Giving exception:   try {
        endpoint.insertCheckIn(checkin).execute();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }... I Guess execute() is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
Actually I was Running my app on actual android device, which was wrong.

Tried Running it on Avd Emulator but it was too slow.
Then I dowloaded BlueStacks Emulator and Run my app on that and I get my entity in the Entity Kind Dropdown menu.